# Outlets & light switches show voltage but do not work ...with a weird CAVEAT!

Tags: electrical

I have an older mobile home that I recently purchased. I had the electrical service started yesterday and I turned on all the breakers in the home. Nothing seemed to be working. I then plugged in the refrigerator and the compressor turned on then made a type of clunking sound and shut itself off.

Here’s the weird part. Even though the refrigerator does not come on now when it’s plugged in it’s appropriate outlet, it affects the light switches and receptacles throughout the house depending on whether it’s plugged in or unplugged. When the refrigerator is plugged in ( *even though the appliance itself is not working* ) all of the light switches and wall sockets in the bedrooms and living room function properly ( *but not the kitchen area* ).

When I unplug the refrigerator all of the light switches and wall sockets in the kitchen begin working but the rest of the house is no longer functioning. I plugged in a generator to the refrigerator and it still works.

Why In the world would the function of light switches and sockets throughout the house vary depending on whether my refrigerator was plugged into its wall socket or not ?

Comment: Did everything work correctly when you purchased it

Comment: DON'T plug in anything else.  This seems like you may have lost a pole or a neutral on your service.  Probably an easy fix, but until you do, it will destroy appliances.  It's time to check it all out with voltmeters etc.  You can safely plug in loads which autoswitch for 120-240V, such as cell phone chargers.

Comment: It might be a similar problem just on the subpanel or branch which serves the kitchen.  Loose neutrals are particularly dangerous like this!

Comment: Do you have a voltmeter/multimeter?